# Populate subelements of a set of lists

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following classes:

```
public class Parent {
    public Parent() 
    {
        children = new List<Child>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Child> children { get; set; }
}

public class Child {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

And the following data:

```
List<Parent> allParents = new List<Parent>() { /* ... */ };
List<Child> allChildren = new List<Child>() { /* ... */ };
```

How would I merge each `Child` in `allChildren` into the correct `Parent` within `allParents` efficiently?

The only solution I can come up with feels really inefficient:

```
foreach (var child in allChildren)
{
    allParents.Where(p => p.Id == child.ParentId).Single().Children.Add(child);
}
```

---

**Edit:**
Thought of an alternative solution:

```
var parents = listOfAllParents();
var allParents = new List<Parent>();
foreach (var parent in parents) {
    parent.children = allChildren.Where(c => parent.Id == c.ParentId).ToList();
    allParents.Add(parent);
}
```

This might be easier to improve since the data is indexed by ParentId...

Comment: I'd load the parents into a `Dictionary<Guid, Parent>` and use that in your loop instead of a Linq query.

Comment: Key == `Parent.Id`? Why would this be better?

Comment: The lookup of the parent from the dictionary would be more efficient than the Linq query because it would give you a constant time lookup where as the Linq query is a linear time lookup.

Comment: @juharr, gotcha, makes sense. I avoided that issue in the updated code, by starting with only the collection of parents.

Comment: `allChildren.ForEach(x => allParents.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id == x.ParentId).children.Add(x));` ?

Comment: @BagusTesa, Microsoft has recommended to not use `.ForEach()` for awhile now.

Comment: @CSmith If you have m parents and n children then both of your solutions run in m * n time where as loading into a dictionary first would run in n + m time

Comment: @juharr, not sure if `.GroupBy()` would get me the same benefits as a dictionary would. The children are indexed by ParentId, so: `var childrenGrouped = allChildren.GroupBy(c => c.ParentId)` should be efficient. After that, I'd just have to do `parent.children = childrenGrouped.Where(g => parent.Id == g.Key).SelectMany(g => g).ToList();` Seem reasonable?

Comment: @juharr, thanks for explaining that... I was missing the point.

Comment: thank you @CSmith for pointing that out, looks like it had concurrency issues and no exception thrown if any of the expression fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two efficient methods, both including preparing a fast hash based lookup data structure and then using it to link the items.

- Using `Dictionary<Guid, Parent>` for locating the parent by `ParentId` of the child:

  ```
  var parentById = allParents.ToDictionary(parent => parent.Id);
  foreach (var child in allChildren)
  {
      var parent = parentById[child.ParentId];
      parent.children.Add(child);
  }
  ```
- Using `ILoookup<Guid, Child>` for locating the children by `Id` of the parent:

  ```
  var childrenByParentId = allChildren.ToLookup(child => child.ParentId);
  foreach (var parent in allParents)
  {
      foreach (var child in childrenByParentId[parent.Id])
      {
          parent.children.Add(child);
      }
  }
  ```

Both solutions have linear time complexity.

Comment: Yep, that's what @juharr was saying in the comments. Didn't know about `ILookup`, that's good to know. Thanks!

Comment: ILookup is basically the same as `GroupBy`, but allows to be used outside LINQ query for searching.

Comment: It just occurred to me, if # of Parents >> # of Children within each Parent, does that make one better or worse than the other? Edit: Yeah, I've always stuck with `GroupBy` for that kind of thing.

Comment: If N=Parents.Count, M=Children.Count, both solutions run with N+M operations. First - N to build the dictionary + M seeks. Second - M to build the lookup + N seeks. The only difference could be in space (memory used), but not significantly. Theoretically if N > M one should use the second approach, else the first would be better.

Comment: Thanks for the followup :)